# alsabar widget not getting displayed (lain)

Tags: awesome-wm

'm trying to add a soundbar to an already existing theme I got. The theme already includes lain so I'm trying to use alsabar since it's already included.

Awesome version:

awesome v4.2 (Human after all)
  • Compiled against Lua 5.3.4 (running with Lua 5.3)
  • D-Bus support: ✔
  • execinfo support: ✔
  • xcb-randr version: 1.5
  • LGI version: 0.9.2
Lain's readme file says that is for awesome WM 4.x so I'm guessing there's not a version issue.

Here's the code:

```
--Volume bar
local volume = lain.widget.alsabar(
    {
    width=200, height=10, followtag = true,
    ticks = true, ticks_size = 10
    }
)

local volume_widget = wibox.container.background(volume.widget)
volume_widget.bgimage=beautiful.widget_display
```

Added it to wibox

```
  spr,
  spr5px,
  -- Volume
  spr,
  volume_widget,
  spr,
```

That's the code. I get no errors volume variable works but the widget is not displayed. I know that the volume variable works because I'm calling it's update() function later in the file.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. Instead of `volume.widget` I had to do `volumr.bar`. which was weird cause all the other widgets of lain in that configuration file we're implemeted using 'widget'.

`local volume_widget = wibox.container.background(volume.bar)`